# npm publish to Artifactory not working

Tags: npm, artifactory

I have setup Artifactory according to the instructions given here, http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Npm+Repositories, but on publishing a package the following is displayed:

```
npm http PUT http://localhost:8083/artifactory/api/npm/npm-local/UIBase
npm http 400 http://localhost:8083/artifactory/api/npm/npm-local/UIBase
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! publish Failed PUT response 400
npm ERR! SyntaxError: Unexpected token M
npm ERR! Missing attachments with tarball data, aborting upload for: 'UIBase'
npm ERR!     at Object.parse (native)
npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:238:23)
npm ERR!     at Request.self.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/index.js:148:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/index.js:896:14)
npm ERR!     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/index.js:847:12)
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at _stream_readable.js:920:16
npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-39-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "publish" "--registry" "http://localhost:8083/artifactory/api/npm/npm-local"
npm ERR! cwd /home/debjit/code/pubmatic/pub-mgmt/ui/UIBase
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! type unexpected_token
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/debjit/code/pubmatic/pub-mgmt/ui/UIBase/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

The command I have used is:

```
npm publish --registry http://localhost:8083/artifactory/api/npm/npm-local
```

Artifactory logs show the following:

```
2014-11-19 23:15:23,541 [http-bio-8083-exec-2] [WARN ] (o.j.r.n.r.h.NpmLocalRepoHandler:192) - Missing attachments with tarball data, aborting upload for: 'UIBase'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should upgrade your npm client and use at least 1.4.3.

The reason is that the publish command has changed and Artifactory supports the newer format.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I also tried npm 2.1.8, which is not supported it seems because I get `2014-11-21 08:29:23,316 [http-bio-8083-exec-1] [ERROR] (o.a.a.n.r.NpmResource:98) - Unsupported npm repository request for 'uibase'`.

Is there a document, specifying which versions are supported?

Comment: There were several issues with npm 2.x. See this ticket: https://github.com/npm/npm-registry-client/issues/78
Basically you should try adding a trailing `/` e.g: `npm publish --registry http://localhost:8083/artifactory/api/npm/npm-local/`