# npm publish to Artifactory results in Failed PUT 302

Tags: node.js, npm, artifactory

When I try to `npm publish` to a private npm repository on Artifactory I get a Failed PUT 302 error. I followed the directions in their video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyQ0riy3Hk8) and set up a remote repository that points to registry.npmjs.org, another that is the private repo(npm-local), and a virtual repo that aggregates the remote and private repos.

I set up my `~/.npmrc` file to use the Artifactory virtual repo and added my credentials. I am able to install public packages fine using this setup. But when I try to publish directly to /npm-local I always get Failed PUT 302 - the repository responds with a generic nginx 302 Found page and npm can't parse the html.

Currently I am using npm@2.13.3 but I even tried reverting back to 1.4.x after reading [npm publish to Artifactory not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27024212/npm-publish-to-artifactory-not-working) and had the same issue.

Also I have tried publishing a directory with package.json in it and a tarball - both produce the same 302 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several emails and a phone call I found the fix:

1. login to artifactoryonline
2. Goto Admin Tab
3. Under general settings set the Custom URL Base to: https://YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME.artifactoryonline.com/YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME

They said that they are working on having this set for you by default but until then you have to set it manually. Unfortunately it is not documented anywhere and not mentioned in any of the videos that I saw.

Answer (score 0):

NPM v6 is not able to handle the HTTP Status 302. It process this code as successful printing PUT 302 into verbose output. It happens for example, if the Artifactory server expects the connection over https and redirects all the requests from port 80 to 443. NPM v8 handles redirects correctly.